# How to change language at runtime in Qt?

Tags: qt

I'm writing a multi-language program with the Qt framework. I want to change the language at runtime. I wrote the code below in a slot but it does not work.

```
    QTranslator translator;
    translator.load("arrowpad_tr");
    qApp->installTranslator(&translator);
```

Comment: I add change event code for my class and add setText() for all widgets but again it does not work...

Comment: thanks @Bart .Ok...I add a QTranslator pointer to my class and before change language call removeTranslator() function and delete the pointer and create a new pointer from QTranslator ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing a translator only means that the specific translator becomes available. This is signaled by a LanguageChange event for the QCoreApplication. What you will still have to call is `retranslateUi();` which will take care of the actual translation for Qt Designer widgets. For custom widgets you will have to create something similar based on the event.

Comment: Beware of retranslateUi bugs like [this one](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-3863).